# Sum of (n mod i) is the range between Triangular and Square number

Tags: number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

I was surprise to find this when working on another [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1656460/sum-of-floor-weighted-divisor-summary-function): 
$$
T_m\leq\sum_{i=1}^n (n \bmod{i}) \leq m^2, \text{ where } m=\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor \text{ and } T_m=\sum_{i=1}^m i
$$

I would like to know what are the known ways to further limit the range of this sum. May I know what is the name of this topic or where can I read about it? Thanks!